# In Powershell, why is it so much slower to find all directory names, than to add up all file sizes?

Tags: performance, powershell, get-childitem

I'm confused by how much slower one of these commands is compared to the other.

This command finds the size of the C:\ drive, by recursively finding the size of every subfolder in C:\

```
$len = 0
gci -path C:\ -recurse -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length}
```

This command finds the name of every folder on the C:\ drive, by recursively looking through every folder on the C:\ drive

```
$result = gci -path C:\ –recurse -force -directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{$_.fullName}
```

Why is the first one so much faster than the second? Is there some kind of caching going on for folder sizes? Is it just a matter of string manipulation being orders of magnitude slower than integer manipulation?

Comment: The second one outputs everything to the console. That's what's slow. If you save the output to a variable instead you will see that it will be much faster.

Comment: You're right, but I tried saving it to a variable and it's still many times slower. Thank you for the comment, I'll fix the example.

Comment: It depends pretty much on your folder structure and on your hardware. For me the second command is even faster. ;-)

Comment: instead of `$result = gci -path C:\ –recurse -force -directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | %{$_.fullName}` why don't just use `$result = (gci -path C:\ –recurse -force -directory -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue).fullName` which avoids the need of a pipe?

Answer (score 1):

Note: as written your first command pushes out a bunch of error messages I cancelled the command because it ran on for some minutes! Although directories  have a length property it is the length of the Full Diretory Path and not the size of the directory in bytes.

```
The property 'length' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property 
exists.
At line:2 char:68
+ ... ecurse -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length}
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PropertyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyNotFoundStrict
```

So I added the -File switch parameter.

```
PS> $len = 0
Measure-Command -Expression {
  gci -path C:\ -File -recurse -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % { $len += $_.length}}

TotalSeconds      : 58.5945269

PS> $len = 0
Measure-Command -Expression {
  $x = gci -path C:\ -File -recurse -force  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
  ForEach ($File in $x) { $Len += $file.length}
}

TotalSeconds      : 48.99365
```

As you can see using the Pipe is considerably slower that saving to a variable, an array in this case, and then processing from that.
I edited out the redundant info output by Measure-Command

In the second command you are not processing files only directories (-Directory) and you are not calculating size thus making it faster.
As you can see this command only returns an array of Strings of the directory paths. (again edited for brevity).

```
PS> $result.count
118148

PS> $result[0] | gm

   TypeName: System.Stri

Name             MemberType            Definition                              
----             ----------            ----------                              
Chars            ParameterizedProperty char Chars(int index) {get;}            
Length           Property              int Length {get;}                       

PS> $result[0].Length
14

PS> $result[0]
C:\$GetCurrent
```

HTH